# How can I pass all command line arguments to a program in a Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I can do:

```
all:
    $(CC) -DFOO=$(FOO) -DBAR=$(BAR) main.c
```

And call it with:

```
make FOO=foo BAR=bar
```

But I want a more generic solution in a way that I don't have to write ALL possible variables in the compiler call line. I know, for example, that MAKECMDGOALS variable has all targets from the command line. There is any MAKECMDVARS-like variable that contains all variables from command line? So I could do something like this:

```
CONFIGS = $(addprefix -D, $(MAKECMDVARS))

all:
    $(CC) $(CONFIGS) main.c
```

Comment: How do you want to distinguish targets from variables? That is, if you call `make foo bar`, should Make try to *build* `foo` and `bar`, or put those names into `MAKECMDVARS`?

Comment: @Beta, I'm considering a variable something like `foo=bar`. This way, `make foo bar` should build `foo` and `bar`. And `make FOO=foo BAR=bar baz` should put `FOO=foo BAR=bar` in `MAKECMDVARS` and build `baz`.

Comment: Why not `make  CFLAGS='-DFOO=foo -DBAR=bar' baz`?

Comment: @Beta, I want to "hide" the underneath implementation to the user by hiding `CFLAGS`. And it is more cleaner if it is possible to avoid typing `-D` and quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion this is a bad idea.  It will break everyone's understanding of how make works, and it will mean you can't use variable overrides for their intended purpose.  What if you *want* to change `CC` for just a single build using make?  Or `CFLAGS`?  Or some other variable?

However, if you really want to do it you can: all variables assigned on the command line are put into the `-*-command-variables-*-` variable:

```
$ echo 'all: ; @echo variables: $(-*-command-variables-*-)' | make -f-
variables:

$ echo 'all: ; @echo variables: $(-*-command-variables-*-)' | make -f- FOO=foo BAR=bar
variables: BAR=bar FOO=foo
```

Comment: I understand. Thanks for the explanation. I will make this temporary until I can deploy a proper autotools build system.